# Search file for word and delete line

Tags: php

This is a second request on the same subject. I wasn't clear
I needed the line to be deleted.

I searched here and found part of a script that is suppose search for
a word and delete the line. There seems to be a slight error with what
I'm trying to do.

I have an option list in a pull down. I would like for it to
remove the line selected. The file choice.php that is called
from the pull down page seems to be released when the php below
is called called because there is no access denied, or violation
errors.

These are the errors I'm getting after adding the 3 last lines I
was told I need.

```
fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given
implode(): Invalid arguments passed
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
//  Separate choice.php has the following pull down 
//  Select item to delete from list
//  <option value="item1.php">Item 1</option>
//  <option value="item2.php">Item 2</option>
//  ...... many items.

$workitem = $_POST["itemtodelete"]; 

$file = file("option.list.php");
foreach( $file as $key=>$line ) {
    if( false !== strpos($line, $workitem) ) {
      unset ($file[$key]);
    }
}
// Removed "\n"
$file = implode("", $file);
// Told to add this.
$fp = fopen ("option.list.php");
fwrite($fp,implode("",$file);
fclose ($fp);

?>
```

Comment: So if I understand, you want to delete lines of the file `option.list.php` which contains the value of `$workitem`, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. You are missing some closing parenthesis, as well as other things.

```
$replaceItem = $_POST['itemtodelete']; // You should filter this data

$newContents = "";
$path = PATH_TO_FILE; // This could be hard coded, but not recommended
$filename = "option.list.php";

// Check to see if the file exists
if ( file_exists($path."/".$filename) ) {
    // Wrap our IO stuff so we catch any exceptions
    try {
        // Open the file for reading
        $fp = fopen($path."/".$filename, "r");
        if ($fp) {
            // Loop line-by-line through the file
            while($line = fgets($fp, 4096) !== false) {

                // Only add the line if it doesn't contain $replaceItem
                // This is case insensitive. I.E. 'item' == 'ITEM'
                // For case sensitive, use strstr()
                if ( stristr($line, $replaceItem) == false ) {
                    $newContents .= $line;
                }
            }
        }
        // Close our file
        fclose($fp);

        // Replace the contents of the file with the new contents
        file_put_contents($path."/".$filename, $newContents);                
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Edit: Try this. I modified it somewhat.

Comment: This replaces the string, not the entire line that contains the string.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I know. I modified it after I realized his question was wanting to remove the line.

Comment: AbraCadaver It deletes the line great. Except with the first line item is selected it deletes all of them.

Comment: Thomas it's giving a syntax error on your while line. T_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry. Extra ')' in the while line. Also make sure that the line is $newContents .= $line. The .= will add the string to the existing string.

Comment: Thomas it's missing a ")" I'm just sure if it goes in front of line or fp.

Comment: It's still crying about a parenthesis? Have you tried the new code? I updated it since that error you were reporting.

Comment: I posted that before yours hit. The error is gone. But it's not deleting the line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59300/discussion-between-thomas-powers-and-user3735995).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59310/discussion-between-bpross-and-thomas-powers).

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` requires a `$mode` as the second parameter, so that fails and everything that needs `$fp`.

Just use `file_put_contents`.  It will even `implode` the array for you:

```
$workitem = $_POST["itemtodelete"]; 

$file = file("option.list.php");
foreach( $file as $key=>$line ) {
    if( false !== strpos($line, $workitem) ) {
      unset ($file[$key]);
    }
}

file_put_contents('option.list.php', $file);
```