# How to search for text in a file and then delete it?

Tags: php

Let's say the content in my txt file is:

```
Hello! This is a test file!

Continued...
```

I understood that the content of the file should be read first:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("test.txt");
```

How do I continue? To search for the text: 'Continued...' delete it, and save the file again.

(Without destroying the rest of the content)

Comment: Is your file an html file? Is your target (`Continued...`) at the start of a line and alone in its line?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i got along with that question, Thx Casimir! can you help me with my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48485979/php-dom-text-saved-as-it-how-to-fix?noredirect=1#comment83964899_48485979

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search file for word and delete line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294244/search-file-for-word-and-delete-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("test.txt");
$newfileContetnt = str_replace('Continued...', '', $file);
file_put_conetnt($newfileContetnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to remove "Continued..." from the text you retrieved with `file_get_contents`, you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php) and then put back the modified content in your text file with [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
$filename = 'test.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
file_put_contents($filename, str_replace('Continued...', '', $content));
```

It is actually pretty close to the [first example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-put-contents-examples) given in the documentation of `file_put_contents`.